# Trying to sort in an API

Tags: python, api

im new in this of "Calling APIs", so i don't understand a lot, I was wondering if anyone can help me.

I want to sort the cryptocurrencies from coinmarketcap whit their API, in the Api documentation, says that there is a parameter 'sort', and i can use differents values, like 'name','symbol' and 'recently added'. So if i want to get the last cryptocurrency listed, i have to sort whit 'recently added'. But i dont know how to do it. Here is a piece of code that i can write, but whit that code i get All the cryptocurrencys and i dont know how to sort it. Thanks

```
import requests
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json

url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest"

parameters = {
  'start':'1',
  'limit':'5000',
  'convert':'USD'
}
headers = {
  'Accepts': 'application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'private key',

}
session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its

```
parameters = {
  'start':'1',
  'limit':'5000',
  'convert':'USD',
  'sort':'recently_added'
}
```

assuming you interpretted the docs right

it actually looks like it want `'sort':'date_added'` NOT `'recently_added'` based on the docs at https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest

Comment: and how i can get the most recently added? because whit that code i get all the cryptocurrencys sort by 'recently added', but i want the most recently only

Comment: @NahueSalis If you sort by date and then take the last one in the sequence, you have the one with the latest date.